# Replace first word of a delimited file

Tags: unix

I need to replace the first word of first line of the file .
Ex: In the below '^' delimited file, i need to replace HEADER1 with PARA1.

```
cat FILE.TXT  
HEADER1^HEADER2^HEADER3^HEADER4^HEADER5^HEADER6  
SUBHEADER1^SUBHEADER2^SUBHEADER3^SUBHEADER4^SUBHEADER5^SUBHEADER6^SUBHEADER7^SUBHEADER8^SUBHEADER9^SUBHEADER10^SUBHEADER11^SUBHEADER12^SUBHEADER13  
10^56^Q1^Q1^95^02^ ^ ^4^20170501^20170501^ABCD^  
20^56^Q2^Q2^95^02^ ^ ^4^20170502^20170502^ABCD^  
30^56^Q3^Q3^95^02^ ^ ^4^20170503^20170503^ABCD^
```

I do not want to use sed to find the first occurence of HEADER1 in the file & replace it.
Instead it should work for any value in first word of the first line of file .

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to use sed because you think it limits you to replace a specific string by another string? sed expects regular expressions, which allow you to do the following:

```
sed -e '1 s/^[^^]*/PARA1/' < /tmp/input.txt
```

This replaces the first word of input (on the first line only) by PARA1, assuming that the words are separated by `^`.

Comment: Thanks W.Mann . This is exactly what i needed.